# Performance degradation in AKS Windows node pool vs. virtual machine-hostes application in IIS

Tags: windows, performance, azure-aks

I am running a sample ASP.NET MVC app (.Net framework 4.8).

Performance tests show max. throughput 12.5k rps for app hosted natively in Windows 2022 server in Azure.
However, when I rung the app in AKS for Windows (same sku size) I experience max. throughput only 9.3k rps.
Latencies are similar in both scenarios, CPU utilization of host VM similar. Network infrastructure setup should be set up properly.

Do you experience similar performance degradation in AKS for Windows?

Comment: Ideally this should not happen, but Windows containers generally have more overhead than Linux containers due to their larger size and the way Windows handles isolation, which can impact performance. I would recommend you to check these things. Ensure that the container is not hitting any resource limits. Kubernetes allows you to specify CPU and memory requests and limits, which can throttle the resources available to your container. I mean multiple things can be there to affect the performance on aks. Could be the node configuration as well.

Comment: @Arko Thank you for your insights. We set properly container memory and CPU limits. I am thinking about how to verify the AKS system services (those pods in system namespace) and their resources utilization.

Comment: Oh in that case for verifying pod resource usage you can just do a kubectl top pod <pod-name> --namespace=<namespace>
or do a kubectl get deployment metrics-server -n kube-system
AKS clusters have Metrics Server installed by default. Or if you had enabled monitoring on your AKS then under monitoring tab on left side of your aks from portal you will see insight. There you can filter out with whatever details you need in terms of CPU or memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several factors that can affect the performance of an ASP.NET MVC app hosted in AKS for Windows. One possible reason for the performance degradation could be the use of shared resources between the system and application nodes. To mitigate this risk, it is recommended to use a dedicated system node pool to reserve space for critical system resources such as system OS daemons, while the application workload runs in a user node pool to increase the availability of allocatable resources for the application. Additionally, it is recommended to review the extensions and add-ons enabled during create provisioning, as they can add latency to the overall duration of create operations. If an extension or add-on is not needed, it is recommended to remove it to improve create latency.

As for verifying the AKS system services and their resource utilization, you can use the Azure Kubernetes Dashboard to view the system namespace and its pods. The Kubernetes Dashboard is a web-based user interface that provides information about the state of the Kubernetes cluster, as well as the ability to manage it. You can use it to view the resource utilization of the system pods and identify any potential bottlenecks.
[image]

It is worth noting that the performance of an ASP.NET MVC app hosted in AKS for Windows can be affected by various factors, such as the VM SKUs used, the use of availability zones, and the number of services on the cluster. Therefore, it is recommended to follow the best practices for performance and scaling in AKS for Windows to optimize the performance of the application.

References:

- [Best practices for performance and scaling for small to medium workloads in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/best-practices-performance-scale#node-scaling-and-efficiency)
- [Azure hosting recommendations for ASP.NET Core web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/azure-hosting-recommendations-for-asp-net-web-apps#web-applications)
- [Frequently asked questions for Windows Server node pools in AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-faq#frequently-asked-questions-for-windows-server-node-pools-in-aks)